# Reducing margin on the left/right side on a "scrreprt" document class

Tags: margins, scrreprt

I am currently writing a report by using a template from the Overleaf website with the following packages/initial settings:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside, openright,titlepage,fleqn,%
              headinclude,footinclude,BCOR5mm,%
              numbers=noenddot,cleardoublepage=empty]{scrreprt} %without space utk jilid

\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[square]{natbib}
\usepackage{subcaption} 
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage{chngpage}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{ccicons} 
\usepackage{xspace} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{scrhack} % ignore warnings about deprecated KOMA-Script
\usepackage{apalike}
\usepackage[printonlyused,smaller,withpage]{acronym}

%for numbering:
\usepackage{enumitem}
%for table splitted to the next page:
\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage[floatperchapter,dottedtoc,eulerchapternumbers,pdfspacing,linedheaders] 
{classicthesis}
\usepackage{arsclassica}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{float}

%for algorithm:
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}


\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\pagestyle{plain}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

This setting gives me a result with margins on the outer side of the page that I feel to be too wide (too much empty space). I want to reduce this margin, therefore I can have less page for the report.

I tried to add DIV=15 or something but nothing works. I also tried to use "geometry" package to manually change the margin but also to no avail. The output seems like the following:

[image: Margin on the outer side is too big.]

Can anyone help me? I feel like there must be a simple solution to this problem. Thank you for your time and attention.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile, it's missing at least a `\end{document}` command and the `mysettings` file is unknown to us. Also, have a look at the `usegeometry` option for all KOMA-script classes. It should allow the use of normal `geometry` commands.

Comment: You are calling classicthesis, which probably overrides most of the KOMA-script commands. Are you sure you need that package?

Comment: @Miyase I see, thank for the input, I modified the content.

Comment: @KeksDose Ah I see, now if I put the  'geometry' package after that 'classicthessis' line, it works. Thank you very much for the tips.